# Logging an array containing classes prints the current version of classes, rather than its state at the time of logging

Tags: javascript, class, logging

I'm new to JS, coming from an iOS and Swift background.

I declare an array containing a class, and then change a value within that class. When I print the class before and after changing the value, it seemingly prints the current version of the class. Here's an example:

```
class Something {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

var somethings = []

somethings.push(new Something("hello"))

console.log(somethings) //object printed with name as "bye"
console.log(somethings[0].name) //"hello"

somethings[0].name = "bye"
console.log(somethings) //object printed with name as "bye"
console.log(somethings[0].name) //"bye"
```

Am I misunderstanding something here? Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: In Chrome it prints just the opposite: `console.log(somethings[0].name)` the first time called, prints `"hello"`, on last line prints `"bye"`.

Comment: My mistake - approved an edit to fix.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your browser. If the browser only keeps the reference on your `somethings` object, it will update in the log, when the real object is updated.

If it logs a copy of the object, it will never change.

For example look at this snippet - when you click "Run code snippet" it logs a copy of the object, therefore it will not change:

```js
class Something {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

var somethings = []

somethings.push(new Something("hello"))

console.log(somethings) //object printed with name as "bye"
console.log(somethings[0].name) //"hello"

somethings[0].name = "bye"
console.log(somethings) //object printed with name as "bye"
console.log(somethings[0].name) //"bye"
```

If you simultaniously open the browser console on this page while pressing "Run code snippet" you will see, that the browser logs it exactly how you described it.